How can I use Bourne shell on Ubuntu?
I want to use Bourne shell (not Bash) in Ubuntu 24.04, but /bin/sh points to /bin/dash, and I cannot find Bourne anywhere. How can it be installed?

What do you mean, or think you mean, by "Bourne shell"? The original version was never ported to Linux, and descendents like Heirloom sh which might work on Linux also have a lot more new features added as well - does that still count as a Bourne shell to you?

Bash stands for "Bourne-Again Shell", and is /usr/bin/bash. Are you sure you don't actually mean Bash?

If you explain why you want the original bourne shell, we might be able to give you some alternatives. I doubt you will ever find a system with the actual bourne shell these days, maybe you just want to learn about POSIX sh?

Oh. I thought that it has been ported to Linux. I know many alternatives.

@kos No, I did not mean Bash. In that case, it is no longer relevant.

Yeah, sorry, I had to ask because (as I'm sure you understand) you have quite the unusual question here (at least for any real practical purpose, I don't think many would be interested in running the original Bourne shell these days). Since there are many users that are new to Linux and that come here asking for help about very basic topics, I had to make sure this wasn't a case of a new user mixing up the two (similar) names

Maybe this question was downvoted because of as Kos noted "[some people] don't think many would be interested in running the original Bourne shell these days", however I upvoted this question back up in order to support software freedom.

Just for completeness sake:
As far as I know, the original Bourne Shell was never ported to GNU/Linux, but instead implemented as Bash. The initial version of Bash was released in 1989, as a free alternative to the commercial Unix Bourne shell.
You might be able to find very early Bourne Shell source code on the Unix Heritage Site. However, it is unlikely that this code can compile on Ubuntu without major modifications. So in short, getting the original Bourne Shell to run might be a major task in itself.
As a rule of thumb, running historical software on modern systems will most likely be a challenge.
